# How to downgrade from android 5.0 to android 4.1 on eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

My application can only be used on android 5.0 or higher. How would I go about downgrading to version 4.1 in eclipse so older phones can use it.

Comment: change minSdk version in your manifest. That might brake your build, but in this case you need to change your code...

Comment: Also if you want to use some nice features you better use support library

Comment: in your manifest file you should have a minimum and maximum api. Jelly Bean (API level 16) is Android  version 4.1 so set that as the minimum api. check here for the syntax you need in your manifest file  -- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is in the documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html
And this is useful fragment from that page:

```
<manifest>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" />
  ...
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

**In case you don´t get a better answer:**

You can create a new project for android 4.1, configure the build path and copy src folder.

Not the best method though. Just the one I normally use (the only one I know) **and works.**